# How can I add a footer-sized image to the bottom of any mobile application?

Tags: android, android-layout, mobile, mobile-application, mobile-development

Is there a way to add a footer-sized image to the bottom of any mobile application?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is by adding a layout set to the bottom of you activity while letting the rest of the screen scrollable. You can achive this by doing the following:

```html
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollablContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/footerView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/headerView" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/footerView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >
        <ImageView
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:src="@drawable/image_name" /> 
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

You can also remove the bottom LinearLayout if you just wish to add an Image and nothing in addition to it. Also similarly a header can be added.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but I was too imprecise with my question. I meant existing mobile applications. I will create a new question, I am sorry.